# Modelling a gradient flow subject to geometric constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-geometry, gradient-flows

Part of the John ellipsoid problem asks the following.
Let $K\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be a convex, symmetric (w.r.t origin), closed set. 
Find the inscribed ellipsoid of largest volume. The existence of such an ellipsoid is a simple continuity argument.

However, I would like to model the John ellipsoid problem as a gradient flow.
An ellipsoid is the image of the Euclidean unit ball $\mathbb{D}$ under a (non-singular) linear transformation $T$. I want to find a $T_0\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, such that
$$
 \left|\det T_0\right| = \max_T \left|\det T_0\right|
$$
subject to the geometric constraint $T_0\left(\mathbb{D}\right)\subset K$.

How can I modify the flow equation for $y\colon [0,\tau) \to \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$
$$
\dot{y}(t) = \nabla \det{y(t)}\phantom{\qquad \ll 1.} \\
y(0) = r\operatorname{Id}_{\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}},\qquad r\ll 1.
$$
so that the geometric constraint $T_0\left(\mathbb{D}\right)\subset K$ is modelled as well?

Comment: From what I know this kind of "inequality" constraint is the kind of thing that is studied in optimal control, so that might be something to read up on, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin%27s_maximum_principle

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll read up a little bit on this.
What a small world! I was at the ANU as a visitor with Ben in 2014 during my master's. Say hi to him for me!

Comment: Are you looking for a numerical implementation or are you working in an abstract setting (looking for existence, unicity, and so on?)

Comment: @Anaedonist I'm not sure yet. I saw the John problem the other day and I'm currently learning about gradient flows, so I thought it would be a fun exercise to simulate the flow and see the convergence to the John ellipsoid. But for that I need to properly describe the flow equation.

Comment: Hah, small world indeed. Another idea is to use a "penalization": subtract a term from your objective function that gets large as you get close to violating the constraint. This should result in a smooth flow (as opposed to something that is smooth up until it hits the constraint and then "turns a sharp corner"), but the choice of penalty term is perhaps not so obvious/natural.

Comment: There are two issues here: (i) how to model $T(\mathbb D)\subseteq K$ as a constraint on the matrix $y$, and (ii) how to define constrained gradient flow as a differential equation. A common approach in numerical optimization for the latter is to add a [barrier function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_function) to the objective you are taking the gradient of, and reduce its weight to zero over time. For the former, I don't have any ideas, but Boyd and Vandenberghe's textbook on convex optimization may have something to say about it (maybe near the section on Chebyshev centers).

Comment: Ah, @Anthony mentioned this idea just as I was writing about it.

Comment: I was right about [Boyd and Vandenberghe](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/), see Sec. 8.4.2 in the PDF.

Comment: @Rahul I read through that part but that is not exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks anyway. 
I want to explicitly use some sort of evolution equation to let an initial small ball flow to the Löwner-John ellipse. Maybe that is just not possible. I guess all geometric flows use either some intrinsic (e.g. Ricci flow) or extrinsic (e.g. mean curvature flow) properties of the set $K$ but not a subset-constraint condition as propose in my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment, but maybe a starting point. Let us name $A = \{x: x \in T(\mathcal{B})\}$ as the candidate maximiser ellipsoid, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the unit ball.
 A formal possibility is to consider an “energy” augmented with a penalty term as follows, $$\mathcal {E} = \det y(t) + \Gamma (A;K)$$
where 
$$ 
  \Gamma (A;K)  = 
    \begin{cases}
      0 \,    & if \,\, A \setminus (A \cap K) = \emptyset   \\
      -\infty & if \,\, A \setminus (A \cap K) \neq \emptyset
    \end{cases}
$$
Informally speaking the penalty term $\Gamma$ “intervenes” when your ellipsoid contains points outside $K$. In a numerical implementation, just use a "sufficiently" large negative number or regularise the penalty term (there is a whole lot of algorithms on the topic, for example used in Finite Element implementations to handle contact).

A possibility is as follows:
$$\Gamma (A;K)  = 
      -\frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \mathcal{L} (A \setminus (A \cap K))    $$
where $\mathcal{L}$ stands for the Lebesgue measure in $\mathcal{R}^n$

EDIT: Would just like to add an idea I was toying with, in 2D. One could define a the analogous of a smooth cut-off function $\chi$, such that its value equals $1$ on $K$ and equals a large negative constant outside $K$. The area $\lvert A \rvert$ of an ellipse could be computed by using Green's Theorem, $$ \lvert A \rvert = \int_{C} x \mathrm{d}y - y \mathrm{d}x$$ where the curve $C$ is the ellipse's perimeter, relatively handy to parametrise. John's problem solution could then maybe be numerically approximated by looking for the maximum of the function  $$ \lvert A \rvert = \int_{C} \chi (x,y) [x \mathrm{d}y - y \mathrm{d}x]$$

Comment: This looks promising and is in light of Anthony's and Rahul's comments.
Maybe something like $\Gamma_\varepsilon(A;K)  = 
      -\frac{1}{\varepsilon^n} \mathcal{L} (A \setminus (A \cap K_\varepsilon))    $ where $K_\varepsilon$ is an $\varepsilon$-neighbourhood of $K$.

Then I would get a sequence of flows $y_\varepsilon$ which hopefully converge to the correct thing as $\varepsilon \to 0$.

Comment: On second thought this particular penalty term might be helpful for the calculus (which I haven't done yet) but is probably quite bad for doing numerical experiments with it.